# How to inject RestTemplate

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired, resttemplate, spring-bean

I am not using xml configurations to define beans. Instead using component scanning and autowire to define and inject dependencies. 
RestTemplate is part of springframework. How can I inject this class ?

Comment: Define an `@Bean`- annotated method in your configuration class, which creates and returns the RestTemplate. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java

Comment: Check out the code on this question for exactly what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473146/java-spring-interceptor-with-no-xml

Answer (score 16):

You do it like any other @Bean in a @Configuration class, and inject with @Autowire - However you question suggest that you should read a little more of the Spring documentation.

```
    @Bean 
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(6);
        template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build()));
        return template;
    }
```

You almost always want to use it together with Apache HttpClient so you get connection pooling. If you need to use it with self-signed https certificates you need a bit more code (let me know if this is the case)